# Угадывание рандомного числа Python

Tags: python

Стоит такая задача

> Напишите программу, которая загадывает случайное число от 0 до 15 включительно, и просит пользователя угадать его с трех попыток.
> При каждом вводе пользователем числа программа отвечает «тепло», если введенное число отличается от загаданного на 2 или меньше и «холодно», если на 3 и больше.
> В каждом ответе программа также подсказывает, больше или меньше введенное число, чем загаданное (выводит на экран "нужно больше" или "нужно меньше").
> Если число угадано точно за 3 попытки – программа завершается и поздравляет пользователя с победой.
> Если нет – выводит какое число было загадано.

Я практически всё сделал, осталось сделать так чтобы он писал холодно или тепло в зависимости от того на сколько отличается выбранное число. Там заготовка у меня есть, но я не знаю как это делать дальше.

```
guesses_made = 0

import random
number = random.randint(0, 15)

print("Загадано число от 0 до 15, отгадайте какое?")
while guesses_made < 3:
    guess = int(input())
    guesses_made += 1

    if guess < number:
        print("Тепло (нужно больше)")

    if guess > number:
        print("Тепло (нужно меньше)")

    if guess < number:
        print("Холодно (нужно больше)")

    if guess > number:
        print("Холодно (нужно меньше)")

    if guess == number:
        break

if guess == number:
    print("Ты угадал мое число!")
else:
    print ("Не угадал! Я загадал число {0}".format(number))
```

Comment: "на сколько отличается" - это разница, вычитание т.е...

Answer (score 0):

```
guesses_made = 0

import random
number = random.randint(0, 15)

print("Загадано число от 0 до 15, отгадайте какое?")
while guesses_made < 3:
    guess = int(input())
    guesses_made += 1
    
    if guess == number:
        break
    
    if abs(number - guess) < 3:
        print("Тепло ", end="")
    else:
        print("Холодно ", end="")
    if guess < number:
        print("(нужно больше)")

    if guess > number:
        print("(нужно меньше)")

if guess == number:
    print("Ты угадал мое число!")
else:
    print ("Не угадал! Я загадал число {0}".format(number))
```

Answer (score 0):

то же, но на Python:

```
import random
number = random.randint(0, 15)

for i in range(3):
     guess = int(input())

     if guess == number:
         break

     print("Тепло" if abs(number - guess) < 3 else "Холодно", end="")
     print("(нужно больше)" if  guess < number else "(нужно меньше)")

else:
     print ("Не угадал! Я загадал число {0}".format(number))

if guess == number:
    print("Ты угадал мое число!")
```